# Access to tty driver from another kernel module

Tags: kernel-module, tty

I want to write a linux kernel module which sends a character over tty to another PC.
Before anyone asks: Yes, it has to be a kernel module. User space isn't available at the point the "message" is send.

What I've got so far is:

I'm using kernel 4.14.

The device file is /dev/ttyS0

The major number for the driver is 4.

I've got a self written kernel module consisting of a function which is executed at the right time.

The problem at hand is, that I don't know how to access the tty driver using the name "ttyS0".
There are so many functions inside the tty driver and I haven't either the tty_struct nor the index (minor number) of the device...

The goal is probrably something like this pseudocode:

```
void MyFunction(void)
{
tty_struct MyStruct* = get_tty_struct("ttyS0");
char message = 'A';
write_to_tty(MyStruct, message);
}
```

Any help on the subject is appreciated.

Greetings

Comment: No, you are not supposed to open files in the kernel, esp. special files. Just use in-kernel APIs for that (the port you are trying to use should have a driver and also serial core framework, use them to provide you necessary information). Look at GNSS subsystem which does a lot of magic to seamlessly connect arbitrary device to a GPS daemon in user space. Yes, it will give you some hints how kernel works in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Meanwhile I've found two ways to write to it:
A "HighLevel" variant and a "LowLevel" variant.

High Level:
Open device file and write to it via a kernel write.

void MyFunction(void)
{
struct file* MyFile = filp_open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_LARGEFILE, 0);
char message = 'A';
int msg_len = 1;
int pos = 0;
kernel_write(MyFile, message, msg_len, &pos);
}

Comment: Low Level: use outb directly for the IO port. NOTE: You have to configure the port correctly before you can use it. See this link: https://wiki.osdev.org/Serial_Ports

Comment: Another remark: I worked on an isolated piece of embedded hardware. So I don't have to worry about multiple parallel accesses to the same port. My solution therefore is kind of a "oneshot" solution.